# Expo Router + Material Top Tabs doesn't render last screen on native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, expo-router

I have a weird problem with Expo Router in combination with Material Top Tabs.
First of all, it works just fine on web.

Second, it works on native when the app is freshly launched.

But after working for one time after that fresh launch, the third/last screen in a Material Top Tabs doesn't render anymore ...

I tried:

- render a simple Hello World instead of what the third screen does,
- changed the order of screens,
- console.log everything,
- useFocusEffect to force a rerender,
- clean setup,
- updated Expo & Expo Router to @latest
- checked all demo code/samples by the package author himself.

Prior to Material Top Tabs, I tried just Tabs by/with Expo Router, and had issues with sorting screens, in my case, I have 3 screens and got breaking errors ...

Can anyone reading this help out?

I am not sharing any of my code, because even a clean setup with simple Hello Worlds, that follow this demo code from the Author doesnt work: https://github.com/EvanBacon/expo-router-layouts-example/blob/main/app/material-top-tabs/_layout.tsx

A hack would suffice, I just need the 3rd/last screen to render on native as it does on web and can move on.

Thanks,